# View All Blogs by a Tumblr User

Tags: oauth, blogs, tumblr

Is there any way that I can view all of the blogs created by a Tumblr user?

I've looked into the API and it seems like I would need that account's OAuth credentials using `user/info`.  Is there any particular tag or user id in a Tumblr blog that would allow me to find other blogs by the same user by using Google or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tumblr does not associate user-id's with users and does not have a user-search so your only option is to use the API.

Also, you could potentially use google to search for blogs, but you would never know whether or not the right person was the user behind the blog since usernames are not necessarily indexed by google.

The only sure-fire way is to use the API, but if you intend to view their blogs yourself this could be a misuse of the api(ie: if the blog is private and you have not been given access).